# How do I store a Li-ion pouch battery without any discharger or balancer?

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, lithium-ion, safety, discharge

I have a single-cell 3.7V 900 mAh Li-ion pouch battery and a 7.4V 30c 2s 850Mah Li-ion pouch battery. I want to store these two batteries (the manufacturer suggests I should store the 2s pack at 3.8V).
The problem is I do not have a discharger or any equipment that can bring down the voltage of the batteries so I can safely store them.

I have a few questions regarding this...

1. can I use up the remaining charge (plugging the battery into a random appliance) until that multimeter reads 3.8V for the 2s pack?
2. When I check the voltage of each cell in the 2s pack, the first cell reads a voltage of roughly 4 volts, and the second cell reads around 8 volts. Why are the cells having two different voltages?
3. What voltage should I store in the single cell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> can I use up the remaining charge (plugging the battery into a random appliance) until...

... that appliance reports that the SoC (State of Charge) is about 50 %. That's it.

Comment: sorry what is SoC?

Comment: State of Charge. Sorry.